# Rails associations in one table (belongs_to :region, has_many :regions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activemodel

I'm trying to create simple geo-model with tree-structure with Rails4. Every region has one parent region and can have many children regions.

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :regions, belongs_to :region, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "regions", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "description"
  t.integer  "region_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Unfortunatelly, such code is not working. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that Rails4 works just as Rails3 in this case:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :regions, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :region
end
```

`has_many` and `belongs_to` are class/singleton methods of Region. Aa such you cannot use one of them as a parameter to the other method.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are looking for a [self join relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins). Try this :

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_regions, class_name "Region", foreign_key: "parent_id" dependent:   :destroy      
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Region"  
end
```

You should have a `parent_id` in your schema as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but what difference between this solution and solution from @maddening?

Comment: No difference except in this case you have `child_regions` and `parent` methods instead of `regions` and `region`. It's also a bit more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :region
end
```

Of course you also need `region_id` integer column in your `regions` table.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about my db schema (added to topic). I already have region_id